# Can I remove the Express version of VS 2012 and 2013 without damaging a professional install on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Apparently I didn't pay attention while installing an SDK and I now have both Professional and Express for Web versions of Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 installed on the same machine. i only use Professional and have never opened the Express version. Can I safely uninstall the Express for web version without adversely affecting the Professional edition? They take 4 GB in total and SSDs don't have that much room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx) implies it should be possible, however there is one thing that will likely break:

> If you uninstall a version of Visual Studio on a computer that has more than one version installed, the file associations for Visual Studio are removed for all versions. You can remap these file associations by using the Restore File Associations button on the Environment, General page of the Options dialog box.

Of course if uninstalling Express does damage Pro somehow, you'll need to repair or even reinstall the Pro version. It only takes a couple of hours nowadays!

Comment: From the wording of that page, it seems like they're talking about something like a 2012 and a 2013 side by side, not an Express and a Professional.